# What is the music playing in the background of the sad scene in episode 9?

Tags: music, akame-ga-kill

In episode 9 [around 2:20](http://www.crunchyroll.com/akame-ga-kill/episode-9-kill-the-battle-fanatic-656911).
What's the music playing in the background during that sad scene?

Comment: [The soundtrack doesn't come out until February 18, 2015.](http://vgmdb.net/album/49690)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the first track on Disc 1 of [Akame ga Kill! Original Soundtrack 1](http://vgmdb.net/album/49690): Le chant de Roma (虐げられた者達の為に), a.k.a. [Fallen Heroes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcmUnLtZ3_I).